# how to Send text to specific contact (whatsapp) number data share

Tags: java, android

How to share data to whatsapp number I want to share data with sendIntent

```
   String share_title = android.text.Html.fromHtml(post.recipe_title).toString();
            String share_content = android.text.Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.share_text)).toString();

            String share_Address = android.text.Html.fromHtml(user.Address).toString();
            String share_pincode = android.text.Html.fromHtml(user.PinCode).toString();
            String share_state = android.text.Html.fromHtml(user.State).toString();

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share_title + "\n\n" + share_content + "\n\n"+ share_Address + "\n\n"+ share_pincode + "\n\n"+ share_state + "\n\n" + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=919773207706"+sendIntent)));
```

This data share wattsapp number sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share_title + "\n\n" + share_content + "\n\n"+ share_Address + "\n\n"+ share_pincode + "\n\n"+ share_state + "\n\n" + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing text in a wrong way. You have to pass text as a parameter like below.

```
String share_title = android.text.Html.fromHtml(post.recipe_title).toString();
    String share_content = android.text.Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.share_text)).toString();

    String share_Address = android.text.Html.fromHtml(user.Address).toString();
    String share_pincode = android.text.Html.fromHtml(user.PinCode).toString();
    String share_state = android.text.Html.fromHtml(user.State).toString();

    String msg = share_title + "\n\n" + share_content + "\n\n"+ share_Address + "\n\n"+ share_pincode + "\n\n"+ share_state + "\n\n" + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
    
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=919773207706&text="+msg)));
```

Comment: how to share wattsapp image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77925465/how-to-slove-this-file-format-not-supported-whatsapp-image