# How to slove this file format not supported whatsapp image

Tags: java, android

this file format not supported whatsapp share image  Toast messgae show how to slove

```
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("image/png");
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello, This is test Sharing");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

Comment: How should be know what image format the file has you want to send via Whatsapp?

Comment: `Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharedPref.getApiUrl() + ....` How should we know what that would be? Which value? Which url,?

Comment: @blackapps  getApiUrl()=jaytn24.com/shopping/

Comment: @blackapps url working bro https://jaytn24.com/shopping/upload/1703038057_product-jpeg.jpeg

Comment: Place your url between ticks as now we can't see protocol. Is it http? https? How can you do without? And better: put it in your code.

Comment: @blackapps
 https://jaytn24.com/shopping/upload/1703038057_product-jpeg.jpeg

Comment: That is still not `between ticks`.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot use a http or https url in EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: how to slove problem bro

Comment: You should share a file from your device. Not from internet.

Comment: If you want to share a link then just share it as text. No need for EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: What ever api image.

Comment: i am new android devloper  what   EXTRA_STREAM

Comment: ok remove extra_stream

Comment: how to share image wattsapp  this  image url  jaytn24.com/shopping/upload/1703038057_product-jpeg.jpeg

Comment: That is no url to begin with. An internet url usually starts with http or such.

Comment: code update  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png");  not working toast messgae show file format not support

Comment: We still cannot see the full url. We cannot see http or https. That's because you did not put the url between ticks. Please do. Fourth time i ask. `https://google.com` like that.